# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am creating small application using Angular 2.In this i need to achieve two way binding in form but it gives me error as above following is the code
[image: Html file]
[image: app.module.ts]

Here is my package.json
"dependencies": {

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^2.0.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0"
```

}

Please Help me out.

Comment: What is `[(ngModel)]` supposed to do on the `<div>`. `[(ngModel)]` is for form controls.

Comment: Why are you using alpha?

Comment: I searched lot according to that every one saying like add formsModule,reactiveformsmodule in app.module.ts but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: So, why do you want to add it to `<div>` when it is (as I mentioned) not supposed to be used with `<div>` what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: yes sir,it was my mistake.According to your suggestion i updated my code and add [(ngModel)] to <input> tag

Comment: Can you please add the code as text instead of as screenshots?

Comment: And? is it working on `<input>` or still not working?

Comment: no still it is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127286/discussion-between-rohit-deshmukh-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Hard to tell with the provided information. Usually adding `FormsModule` to `imports` is enough.